# Migrate path from 2 to 3?

Tags: migration, composer

Anyone have experience updating a CraftCMS site from 2.* to the 3-beta? I'm not in dire need of this at the moment, but can't seem to find it in the developer resources.

EDIT: Found the upgrade guide https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/upgrade.html

Comment: Is your edit the answer? Probably best to post that as an actual _answer_, instead of dropping it back into the question.

Answer (score 5):

The documentation posts this link:
[Upgrading from Craft 2](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/upgrade.html)

Mijingo has a tutorial: [Upgrading Craft 2 to Craft 3](https://mijingo.com/lessons/upgrade-to-craft-cms-3/)

There is a hangout on the topic on Straight Up Craft: [Migrating a website with plugins from Craft 2 to Craft 3](https://straightupcraft.com/events/migrating-a-website-with-plugins-from-craft-2-to-craft-3)

At the time of this posting, I have not seen any good documentation on how Plugin Developers should approach migrating their plugins.

Comment: The official "Upgrading from Craft 2" docs have moved to https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/upgrade.html

Comment: Yes, the docs have recently changed. There used to be two ways, full and simple only via some config. Now only the full way AKA create a new project and import contents is described.